# Button created dynamically properties not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I'm confused as to why this isn't working...

Here's a brief description of what I've declared my buttons dynamically as the form loads because the form resizes itself depending on whats selected.  I've named the buttons button1 and button2.  I've added a handler to button2 to handle when the button gets clicked.  GetButtonColl is called after the buttons are created and I verified it's populated with the buttons on the form.  Why doesn't a simple .enable property work on these dynamically created buttons?  Is there something I need to do different?

Here's a condensed version of my code:

```
Public buttonColl As New List(Of Button)

  '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Function: GetButtonColl
    ' Parameters: none
    ' Returns: none
    ' Description: Loops through all the controls on the form and searches for buttons that were created after the form has been resized
    ' and adds them to a List which will be used to quickly control the buttons properties throughout the session
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Sub GetButtonColl()

        For x As Integer = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
            Dim b As Control = TryCast(Me.Controls(x), Control)
            If b IsNot Nothing AndAlso b.Tag Is Nothing Then
                If TypeOf (b) Is Button Then
                    buttonColl.Add(b)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

Public Sub button1_Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Try
           For Each bttn As Button In buttonColl
                If bttn.Name = "button2" Then
                    bttn.Enabled = False
                End If
            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
         End Try
End Sub
```

Here's how I'm creating my buttons through the code:

```
 btn = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
            With btn
                .Enabled = true
                .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 332)
                .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(122, 26)
                .Name = "button1"
                .Text = "TestButton"
                .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
                .Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
                .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
                .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
                .RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No
                .TabIndex = TabIndex
                .UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(btn)
```

Comment: `button1_Handler` has no handler (no Handles...) so unless you are dynamically adding a handler (code shows none), maybe it is not running.  Add a breakpoint to see.

Comment: I have debugged and confirmed that the handler I have for button1 hits the button1_handler sub routine.  I've added the handler in the function that dynamically creates the button1 control

Answer (score 1):

Simplify. The sender object is the button clicked on just cast it back.

```
Public Sub button1_Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
 Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
 If btn.Name = "button2" Then
    btn.Enabled = False
 End If
End Sub

btn = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
With btn
 .Enabled = true
 .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(9, 332)
 .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(122, 26)
 .Name = "button2" 'wouldn't this be button2?
 .Text = "TestButton"
 .BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
 .Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
 .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 11.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
 .ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText
 .RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No
 .TabIndex = TabIndex
 .UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
 Addhandler btn.Click, AddressOf button1_Handler 'add the delegate
End With
Me.Controls.Add(btn)
```

Also add the `Button` to the `List` when you create it, if you need it in a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Are the buttons directly contained within the form, or are they inside another panel?  Looping through `me.controls` will not get grandchild controls, it isn't recursive.

Comment: I"ve updated my first post showing how I add the buttons to the form.  I am able to pickup the buttons through looping through me.controls

Comment: @Criel, I updated my answer - you were missing the delegate for the click event.